# J2EE Jersey File Upload - input is always null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, upload, jersey, multipart

I try to create a restful service that uploads a file. I followed the steps of:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

But, when I upload a file (for example, a .pdf), the input FormDataMultiPart is always NULL and I don´t understand why. I use the libs "jersey-multipart" and "jersey-core". My code:

Restful service:

```
 @Path("/reservation")
    public class ReservationWs {

        /** The Constant log. */
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReservationWs.class.getName());

        private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://opt/share/reservation/";

        @POST
        @Path("/upload")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public Response uploadFile(
                @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

            String uploadedFileLocation = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER
                    + fileDetail.getFileName();

            // save it
            saveFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

            String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

        }

        @POST
        @Path("/upload2")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public Response uploadFile2(FormDataMultiPart form) {

             FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("file");

             ContentDisposition headerOfFilePart =  filePart.getContentDisposition();

             InputStream fileInputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

             String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + headerOfFilePart.getFileName();

            // save the file to the server
            saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

            String output = "File saved to server location using FormDataMultiPart : " + filePath;
            System.out.println(output);

            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

        }
    }
```

My client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload a File</h1>

    <form action="reservation/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="55" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to call to "upload", the input is null and the error logs:

> GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [rest_1288520529] en el
>   contexto con ruta [/checking] lanzó la excepción [Error processing
>   webservice request] con causa raíz java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.checking.reservation.ws.ReservationWs.uploadFile(ReservationWs.java:74)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89)   at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

When I try to call to "upload2", the input is null and the error logs:

> sep 11, 2015 9:12:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [rest_348842263] en
>   el contexto con ruta [/checking] lanzó la excepción [Error processing
>   webservice request] con causa raíz java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.checking.reservation.ws.ReservationWs.uploadFile2(ReservationWs.java:90)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165)
>     at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89)   at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:198)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a not good solution for now.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, @QueryParam("fileName") String fileName){
    ...
    ...
    String uploadedFileLocation = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER+ fileName;//fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    saveFile(file, uploadedFileLocation);
    ...

    //Logic of the service.
    ...

    //Delete file from local.
}

private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) throws IOException {

    OutputStream outpuStream=null;
    try {
            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();

    } catch( IOException e){
        LOGGER.debug("[UploadWs - saveFile] - error: "+e);
    } finally{
        if(outpuStream!=null){
            outpuStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

"fileDetail" is always null and I don´t know why (if anyone knows the solution, say it) so I add the parameter "fileName" (name of the file) that the client send me. I build the location, I save the file in local, the logic of the service is executed (in my case, I send an email with this file) and I delete the file from local.

It's not a good solution because I add an unnecesarry parameter and I save the file in local.